# Подскажите метод, который подсчитает количество повторений у каждого элемента в списке. Python

Tags: python

Подскажите метод, который подсчитает количество повторений у каждого элемента в списке. Python

Comment: from collections import Counter?

Comment: Словарь?
Незнаю.
Думаю list.count() сойдёт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [1,2,3,2,1,5,6,5,5,5]

import collections
print len([item for item, count in collections.Counter(a).items() if count > 1])
```